# How should I tame my overgrown Phalenopsis?

Tags: plant-health, plant-recommendations, orchids

My phal finished blooming last week, so I am now ready to repot. However, the plant has gotten quite unruly.  It's about 5.5" from the soil line to the center of the top leaf, has developed a fairly substantial keiki two leaves up from the base, and has a plethora of roots growing well above the soil.

What's the proper course of action for repotting and/or taming it?

Edit to clarify the current setup and routine:
The pot has a layer of pebbles at the bottom to keep the plant from sitting in water. It also has a few pebble between the pot and saucer to keep the pot out of the water.

No white stuff on the top of the soil. Speaking of which the soil is actually a orchid potting mix, Miracle-Gro's I believe, with a little bit of sphagnum moss mixed in to help it retain some water.

It is watered once a week using distilled water with a teaspoon of Better-Gro's Orchid Plus Plant Food (20-14-13) per gallon, as they recommend.

Side A:

[image: side A]

Side B, with most of the keiki leaves:

[image: Side B, with most of the keiki leaves]

Edit to show off the blooms:
[image: Showing off the blooms]
[image: Showing off the blooms 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd get a slightly larger, maybe 2" bigger in diameter pot that is terracotta. It breathes.  Lift the pot off the saucer so that it never sits in excess water.  You must be doing well with watering...definitely don't over water.  Can't see the top of the soil...does it have white stuff on top?  Are you watering with tap water or well water?  Use STERILIZED POTTING SOIL that has bacteria and mycorrhysae incorporated.  Do not use garden soil...get a pot that is wider than its height. Water with distilled water or a friend's well water.  Tap water is full of salts, chlorine, fluorine and even we should not drink this stuff.  Fertilize with Osmocote 14-14-14 or 16-16-16 twice per year and no more!  This plant is indoors 100% of the time?  Do you have a shaded porch it could go out on during the summer months?  That would extend its life tremendously.  Very healthy plant...make sure you don't replant repot in too large of a pot. This looks like an 8" pot (I think) so no more than a 10" pot.  In the spring get another that is 12".  Don't worry about the adventitious roots, just shows it needs a bit more room.

Comment: Carefull with recommending potting soil! This is an ORCHID! Also OP should not change the established feeding routine and those roots all over the place is normal, DO NOT try to stuff them all into a pot. Orchids' roots are different!

Comment: Stephie...what soil would you recommend?  Garden soil is a big no-no.  There are potting soils made for orchids of course.  Definitely leave the adventitious roots alone, but make no mistake, too large of a pot is disastrous.

Comment: I should add this plant would love a bit more light.  See how it is severely angled toward the window? Perhaps a decent grow light?  Keep it out of direct sun but the light needs to be increased.  Do get rid of tap water for watering. Must be a beautiful flower.  I love the roots and dark green leaves!  Going out on a shaded porch, out of the wind but increasing the 'light candles' will help this plant add to its root system and be more hardy for indoors during the winters.  Be careful not to take outside too early or back inside too late!

Comment: Thank you very much stormy and @Stephie. I added a few details to the post in response to your comments, also a few pictures of the orchid in bloom because I like showing it off. If you have a recommended potting mix to use I would appreciate hearing about it. I have a north-facing shaded porch that I could give a try, but the orchids that I have kept in that window previously did not fare very well. Do either of you have any recommendations for a good source to research a grow light setup?

Comment: What window orientation is it in right now?  Your plant looks so very happy/healthy.  Stay there!! How long have you had this plant?  Whatever you are doing, LOOKS fine.  You need a bit larger pot, but still waiting for Stephie to tell us what soil is better!  I love this gal, she is brilliant...but ONLY use sterilized potting soil.  There are ORCHID mixes that are more acid...but in no way use garden soil, EVER for plants that are reliant on what you give them in pots!!  Has this plant ever been out of doors on a shaded porch when the weather is wonderful? Kiss kiss, Stephie!! Grins!!

Comment: @stormy, is sterilized potting soil actually a thing you can buy?  I've used a microwave to sterilize soil in the past, but I'm fairly sure that kills all the microorganisms indiscriminately.  Are you sure that "sterilized potting soil that has bacteria and mycorrhysae incorporated" is actually a thing that exists?

Comment: Yes.  You have to find sterilized potting soil that has the bacteria and mycorrhysae incorporated.  In a large garden outside there is a balance.  To just put a bit of that soil into a pot is ludicrous.  No proper soil profile, too little organic matter, one pathogen and the plant is screwed, horrid pore space capacity...a plant in a pot needs some forethought.  What did you think of the smell when you used the microwave?  So very much easier to purchase sterilized soil.  Lots of brands have the bacteria and fungi added to the mix.  Otherwise one could do it themselves.  Lots of products avail

Comment: Interesting - could you post a link to a specific soil like that?  You say "lots of products avail" but I've never seen such a thing, so I'm curious if we're talking about the same stuff.  (Specifically referring to soil that has been sterilized, then had mycorrhysae added).

Heh, yeah, I was worried about the smell before using the microwave, but it turned out to be not too bad!  It was like the normal "dirt" smell, only much stronger.  I'd be scared to try it with something that had recently-composted ingredients.

Comment: I'll have to go find the names but I am pretty sure that Dr. Earth has a soil mix, the FROG brand, and there are packets of just mycorrrhizae to add to plain sterilized cheaper potting soils...as well as bacteria.  Just heard that the vermiculite added might not be too healthy.  I'll go get some brands for you.  Make sure when you repot that you don't use any rock or gravel below the soil!  Use just soil in that pot, use potting feet or pieces of tile to raise the bottom of the pot off the surface.  A great place to find specialized soils etc would be a 'pot' specialty store.

Comment: I am using HAPPY FROG soil with Mycorrhizae and beneficial bacteria included in the mix... this season.  Pot is such a babied plant that you will find great stuff in the 'marijuana' growing shops!  Surely your orchids should be babied!  Make sure the pots do not sit in water in the saucers.  Some grow by watering from below but that works in hot and dry weather and usually out of doors.  Have you had the chance to go shopping?  What have you found?

Comment: It's amazing how much awesome stuff they sell at those shops!  I've seen that Happy Frog soil at such stores, and you're the second person to recommend it.  Thanks!

Comment: Those stores are for serious gardeners!!  Grins.  btw I was given a gift of a SUPER gardening book...one of the best I've ever seen!  By Jorge Cervantes "The Cannabis Encyclopedia".  All based on gardening ONE type of plant.  Instead of having to deal with all the differences between different plants by focusing on ONE plant the amount of detail is flat out amazing.  Completely relevant for all plants.  Take a peek your next visit!  And you are welcome!!